# Webkit / Chrome bug with padding in grid container

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-grid

Wrong height of the grid container when I use the percentage for items.

For example, simple use in the source code or Variant 2 for real tasks.

The problem is webkit, Firefox does not experience this problem.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, auto));  Variant 2 */
  background: black;
}

.grid__item {
  width: 10%;  /* Remove for Variant 2 */
}

.grid__item-inner {
  padding-top: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fixed in version 11.1 safari**

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about CSS Grid is that you can set the width and height of grid items at the container level.

Normally an element, including a flex item, must have its dimensions set on itself. Not so with Grid. The container can manage all dimensions for the grid items (using `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`) without touching the items.

In this particular case, if you removed the specific sizing on the grid item (`width: 10%`) and set it on the container, the layout works on both Chrome and Firefox.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 10%);
  background: black;
}

.grid__item { }

.grid__item-inner {
  padding-top: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <div class="grid__item-inner">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5c6qaj3p/2/)

Comment: Thank you. But I can not solve my primary task. I have to use behaviors for the grid: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, auto));` instead of the one you proposed

Comment: Okay. Maybe you can provide a more detailed explanation. What's the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/5c6qaj3p/3/